# Manually creating an SqlRowSet

Tags: java, jdbc, easymock

I am using EasyMock and need to set expectations on a method that returns an SqlRowSet. Below is a snippet of code.

```
  // SqlRowSet rowSet = new SqlRowSet(); <-- NOT SURE HOW TO MANUALLY CREATE THIS?    
    expect(myDao.getCustomerData("All_CUSTOMERS")).andReturn(rowSet);
```

Anybody know how to manually create an SqlRowSet?

Answer (score 0):

For these types of scenario (i.e. creating a concrete instance of a class is difficult), I typically create a mocked instance. Such as:

```
SqlRowSet mockedSqlRowSet = createMock(SqlRowSet.class);
```